# Regex optional non-capturing groups

Tags: javascript, regex

i am a total Regex Noob and spent hours trying to solve this puzzle.
I think I have to use some kind of optional non-capturing groups or alternation.

I want to match the following strings:

> 1. Neuer Film a von 1000
> 2. Neuer Film a von 1000 mit b
> 3. Neuer Film a von 1000 mit b und c
> 4. Neuer Film a von 1000 mit b und c und d
> 5. Neuer Film a mit b
> 6. Neuer Film a mit b und c
> 7. Neuer Film a mit b und c und d

My regex looks like this:

```
var regex = /(?:[nN]euer [Ff]ilm\s?)(.*)(?:[vV]on).(\d{4}).(?:[Mm]it)(.*)(?:[uU]nd)(.*)/g;
```

The problem is it matches only string 3 and 4. And it does not match the last two "und", but packs it in group No.3 not in group No.4.

Can someone please help with my Regex (which is not very user friendly at all ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You really need to use non-capturing *optional* groups (like `(?:...)?`), but besides, you also need *anchors* (`^` to match the start of the string and `$` to match the string end) and *lazy dot matching patterns* (`.*?`, to match as few any chars as possible).

You may use

```
/^[nN]euer [Ff]ilm\s*(.*?)(?:\s*[vV]on\s+(\d{4}))?(?:\s+[Mm]it\s*(.*?)(?:\s*[uU]nd\s*(.*))?)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8KFQ7Y/3). In the demo, `/gm` modifiers are necessary since the input is a multiline string.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of a string anchor
- `[nN]euer [Ff]ilm` - `Neuer film` / `Neuer Film` / `neuer Film`
- `\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (that is, up to the *leftmost* occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns)
- `(?:\s*[vV]on\s+(\d{4}))?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `\s*` - 0+  whitespaces
  - `[vV]on` -  `von` or `Von`
  - `\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(\d{4})` - Group 2: 4 digits
- `(?:\s+[Mm]it\s*(.*?)(?:\s*[uU]nd\s*(.*))?)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `[Mm]it`  - `Mit` or `mit`
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(.*?)` - Group 3 matching any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
  - `(?:\s*[uU]nd\s*(.*))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

    - `\s*[uU]nd\s*` - `und` or `Und` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
    - `(.*)` - Group 4 matching any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

```js
var strs = ['Neuer Film a von 1000','Neuer Film a von 1000 mit b','Neuer Film a von 1000 mit b und c','Neuer Film a von 1000 mit b und c und d','Neuer Film a mit b','Neuer Film a mit b und c','Neuer Film a mit b und c und d'];
var rx = /^[nN]euer [Ff]ilm\s*(.*?)(?:\s*[vV]on\s+(\d{4}))?(?:\s+[Mm]it\s*(.*?)(?:\s*[uU]nd\s*(.*))?)?$/;
for (var s of strs) {
   var m = rx.exec(s);
   if (m) {
     console.log('-- ' + s + ' ---');
     console.log('Group 1: ' + m[1]);
     if (m[2]) console.log('Group 2: ' + m[2]);
     if (m[3]) console.log('Group 3: ' + m[3]);
     if (m[4]) console.log('Group 4: ' + m[4]);
   }
   
}
```

Comment: Non-capturing groups still *consume* text, they are not zero-width assertions like lookbehinds or lookaheads.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I never thought that I have to use non-capturing groups optional like you described, because I still wanted them to appear in a matching group (thought `(...)?` is enough). And I also never thought of this lazy dot matching. But I still dont understand why the first "und" is not captured while the following "und" are captured, although they are in a non-capturing group?

Comment: The `.*?` matches as few chars as possible, so, the regex gets to the *leftmost occurrence* of the `und` (matched, not captured, with `\s*[uU]nd\s*`). Note that the lazy patterns do not match the *shortest* substrings between 2 strings (as is stated in some SO answers), they just match up to the leftmost occurrences of the subsequent subpatterns.

Comment: I added details and shortened the regex a bit since some non-capturing groups (that are not quantified, nor contain alternation) were redundant.